# how to get all content inside a collection in mongodb for express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to display all things in the collection(called users). But my code only shows [] empty.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');
let db = mongoose.connection;
const User = require('../models/userSchema');

db.collection("users").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
```

I also tried, but it shows User.find(...).toArray is not a function

```
User.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because find is returning a promise. Your code is not waiting for the response and the array will be always empty.

```
User.find({}).then((users) => {
    //doing stuff with the user array
    console.log(users);
});
```

An other option is the await keyword. Await is only available in async functions and your code looks like you are not using the statement in a function. So to use await you need to define an anonymous async function.

```
(async () => {
    //await tells your code to wait till the result comes back
    const users = await User.find({});
    //doing stuff with the user array
    console.log(users);
})();
```